# Least privellages for UDP Listener?

Tags: c#, udpclient

I have a windows service that is listening to UDP packets and forwards them (as well as other things) via HTTP and I'm interested in giving it the least privileges as possible.

I'm unsure whether UDP listening requires special/admin privileges?

I am using UDPClient.Listen on port 1813.

My understanding of [Network Service is that it uses the login credentials for network shares / domain access etc](https://superuser.com/a/255064/27061), not that it is regarding outgoing http connectivity?

Comment: I've added additional detail

Comment: I'll remove my comments about directory access, they're a separate subject matter and correct I should research more and I'll clarify my part about network service file shares.

Comment: Thanks for the edits & help Manfred. For caster of the vote to close, is this now sufficient detail?

Answer (score 0):

UDPListner works correctly using the built in "Local Service" account and does not require "Network Service" nor admin permissions (the problem I was trying to diagnose was unrelated to udp listening in the end).

I believe (albeit not conclusively) also because I'm listening on a port above 1023 then it does not require admin privileges to listen on, nor does it require netsh to allow that port.